# TABLE OF NUMBERS Oracle stored procedure Parameter, How to pass it from C#

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

I am looking for a way to pass the parameter type 'TABLE OF NUMBER' to ORACLE SP from C#. I am using 'Oracle.DataAccess'. I tried using the UDT method but its not working

```
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter param1 = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter("IN_ACCT_ID_ARR", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Ref, ParameterDirection.Input);
param1.CollectionType = Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
//  param1.UdtTypeName = "num_list";
param1.Value = acctId;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
```

Comment: I got invalid binding error.

Comment: Somehow following solution is working... But I am not providing the parameter name . `    OracleParameter inputParameter = new OracleParameter();
                inputParameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32;
                inputParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                inputParameter.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
                inputParameter.Value = acctId.ToArray();`

Comment: So is it working now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked out in the following way..

```
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            OracleParameter inputParameter = new OracleParameter();
            inputParameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32;
            inputParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            inputParameter.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
            inputParameter.Value = acctId.ToArray();

            cmd.Parameters.Add(inputParameter);
```